# Definition of Outer Product of (abstract) vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products

I was reading an article from the American Mathematical Monthly on the Caratheodory derivative for functions of several variables, and in one of the proofs the authors construct a linear transformation by taking a tensor product, which they define as the following:

If $u\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $v,w\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ then $u\otimes v$ is defined by $(u\otimes v)w=(v\cdot w)u$.

This makes sense, we're defining the linear transformation with that property. In terms of matrices this is just $uv^{T}$. But on Wikipedia they've got this definition (on the 'Outer Product' page):

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces. Given $x\in V$ and $y^{*}\in W^{*}$, then the tensor product $y^{*}\otimes x$ is the map $A:W\to V$ given by $w\mapsto y^{*}(w)x.$

My issue with this is that it seems backwards. In the first definition for real vectors, $v$ was the dual vector and it was on the right of the $\otimes$ symbol, whereas Wikipedia's definition puts the dual vector on the left. Is this a different convention, or is one simply an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just different conventions. In general one can choose to view any tensor product
$$ W_1\otimes\cdots\otimes W_p\otimes V^* \otimes U_1\otimes\cdots\otimes U_q $$
as the vector space of linear transformations
$$ V \to W_1\otimes\cdots\otimes W_p\otimes U_1\otimes\cdots\otimes U_q $$
and the two conventions you quote are just particular instances of that idea with $(p,q)=(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ respectively. (The first one further uses the standard dot product to identify $V^*$ with $V$).